AWS Opensearch connectivity with io.searchbox jest in spring boot application
I am trying to connect to opensearch which is deployed on aws with EC2 instance created. I've created an IAM roles and using that to access OS.
I am trying to make a connection to opensearch which is deployed on AWS. I've created an IAM role that is to be used for the authentication when i send any request to opensearch. When I try to execute any query through jestclient, i get an error unauthorized 401, don't know where I am going wrong. Please look into it and let me know what can I do to fix it. Also let me know if you need any other details.
Also sharing the bit of code for you all to analyze.
@Configuration
public class OpenSearchConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OpenSearchService.class);

    private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "es";  // Elasticsearch service name for AWS
    private static final String REGION = "XXXX";  // Replace with your OpenSearch region
    private static final String OPEN_SEARCH_ENDPOINT = "END_POINT URL";  // Replace with your OpenSearch endpoint

    @Bean
    public JestClient jestClient() {
        // Create a signer
        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        signer.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME);
        signer.setRegionName(REGION);

        // Interceptor for signing requests
        HttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AWSRequestSigningApacheInterceptor(SERVICE_NAME, signer, new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());

        // Jest client configuration
        HttpClientConfig clientConfig = new HttpClientConfig.Builder(OPEN_SEARCH_ENDPOINT)
                .multiThreaded(true)
                .build();

        // Jest client factory
        JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory() {
            @Override
            protected HttpAsyncClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder builder) {
                return builder.addInterceptorLast(interceptor);
            }
        };
        factory.setHttpClientConfig(clientConfig);
        logger.info("connection successful");

        return factory.getObject();
    }
}


public class OpensearchApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JestClient jestClient;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OpensearchApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OpensearchApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Search search = new Search.Builder(query)
                .addIndex(index)
                .build();

        try {
            SearchResult result = jestClient.execute(search);
            logger.info("Search response: {}", result.getJsonString());
            if (!result.isSucceeded()) {
                logger.error("Search failed: {}", result.getErrorMessage());
            }
            System.out.println(result.getJsonString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Search request failed", e);
        }
    }

